# How can I group multiple Numbers (populations of cities) from a text file?

Tags: javascript

I need to get an output containing the following in JavaScript; a population < 5000 > 7499, < 7500 > 9999, < 10000, and record blank populations as NA.

This project is representing a report for grouped populations. I honestly don't have a clue how to go about this and would appreciate any help. If what I'm asking doesn't make sense I can try and clarify.

Here are the populations that are in the text file that need grouped:

```
Philadelphia city   1,526,006

Pittsburgh city 305,704

Harrisburg city 49,528

Altoona city    46,320

State College borough   42,034

Monroeville municipality    

Johnstown city  20,978

Murrysville municipality    20,079

McKeesport city 

Greensburg city 14,892

Indiana borough 13,975

Washington city 13,663

Meadville city  

New Kensington city 13,116

St. Marys city  13,070

Lower Burrell city  11,761

Munhall borough 

Jefferson Hills borough 10,619

Waynesboro borough  10,568

Oil City city   10,557

Uniontown city  10,372

Lock Haven city 9,772

Jeannette city  9,654

Beaver Falls city   

Swissvale borough   8,983

Mechanicsburg borough   8,981

Carbondale city 

Latrobe city    8,338

Grove City borough  8,322

Pleasant Hills borough  8,268

White Oak borough   

DuBois city 7,794

Monessen city   7,720

Connellsville city  7,637

Gettysburg borough  7,620

California borough  6,795

Somerset borough    6,277

Clearfield borough  

McKees Rocks borough    6,104

Punxsutawney borough    5,962

Duquesne city   5,565

Shippensburg borough    5,492

Fox Chapel borough  5,388

Turtle Creek borough    5,349

Clarion borough 5,276

Vandergrift borough 

Westmont borough    5,181

Arnold city 

Kutztown borough    5,012
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to split your text file against the line breaks (`\n`). You can then `map` over that array and use a regex to match the name and population and return a useful object.

```
const result = file.split('\n').map(el => {
  const [whole, name, number] = el.match(/^([a-zA-Z\. ]+) ?([0-9,]*)$/);
  const population = +number.replace(',', '')
  return { name, population };
});
```

You can then filter on that returned array of objects and return the subset of records that match the condition.

```
const gt5000lt7500 = result.filter(city => city.population > 5000 && city.population < 7500);
```

[Here's a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/apjo0fzp/2/).

Comment: Ok I'll give that a try! Thank you!